# How to draw a diagram for this right triangle problem?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, word-problem

Recently I came across this problem:

Mathlete was 100 yards from the foot of a vertical rock climbing all and could spot Slowpoke at a 60°angle of elevation still on his way up the wall.  Speedy reached the top of the wall and spotted his car on the ground at a 60° angle of depression.  The car was 425 yards from the foot of the wall.  How many more yards up the wall did Slowpoke need to climb?(Assume that Mathlete, Slowpoke, Speedy, and the care are all on the same vertical plane perpendicular to the wall.)

I'm having a really hard time drawing the diagram for this.  For one, I'm not sure which angle they mean when they say elevation and depression, and the last part saying they are all on the same vertical plane perpendicular to the wall is really confusing me.  I thought that Mathlete was on the ground and Speedy and Slowpoke are on the wall?  I'd really appreciate it if someone could either provide me with a diagram or walk me through how to get one.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is just a rough sketch, but I hope it helps! I haven't labeled it so you can try to figure out some things on your own!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Angles of elevation and depression are always measured from the horizontal. Letting $C,M,F,S,P$ represent the car, Mathlete, the foot of the wall, Speedy and Slowpoke respectively, we get

[image]

The wall itself is $FP$. The "same perpendicular plane" condition prevents the problem from becoming 3D (and therefore introducing new variables that would have to be resolved).